# jQuery form Submit event only works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code:

```
$("#addhash").submit(function(event) {
        // Cancel the default action
        event.preventDefault();

        // Store the value and remove any white space or disallowed chars
        var hash = $("#hashtoadd").val().replace(/\s/g, "").replace(/\W/g, "");

        // Check if anything was entered
        if(hash) {
            // Add the hashtag to the array
            hashes.push(hash);
            localStorage.hashes = JSON.stringify(hashes);
            var key = hashes.length - 1;

            // Clear the form field
            $("#hashtoadd").val("");

            // Set others to inactive
            $("#hashes").children().removeClass("active");

            // Add it to the list and make it the active page
            $("#hashes").append("<li class='active' id='" + key + "'><a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a><a class='hashtag' href='#" + hash + "'>#" + hash + "</a></li>");

            // Load the tweets
            getTweets(hash);
        }
});
```

This code will only work in Chrome. It appears as though `event.preventDefault();` isn't even firing. I tried to put an alert dialog at the very beginning, but that's not showing either which leads me to believe it never even gets in here. I've tried using just a `click ()` event and also using just a `submit()` event, but those don't work either.

**EDIT:** I think the problem is that the event handler is never being called in the other browsers. I've updated the code to reflect how it currently is. Still not working though.

**EDIT2:** As requested, here is the form itself:

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-right" id="addhash">
    <div class="input-prepend input-append">
        <span class="add-on">#</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="tag" tabindex="1" id="hashtoadd">
        <button class="btn" type="submit" href="#" id="submit"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you verify that the handler is called in other browsers?

Comment: Put `alert("yep");` at the top of the function.

Comment: Oh okay that's what I was trying to explain. So I guess the answer is no, the handler never gets called.

Comment: Is #addhash a <form> element?

Comment: Are you using the latest version if jQuery `1.8.3`? Did you actually include jQuery? Do you have an example to look at since this could be many things? One possibility would be if your dynamically creating the submit button you will need to attach the submit handler to something like the document. Also [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) as of jQuery 1.7 has been deprecated and you should be using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: It's safe to assume I included jquery since it works in Chrome. But yes, I included jquery. I am using the latest version. I did not know about the deprecation of live(), I will make the changes, but the submit button is not being created dynamically. I actually have this as .submit() in my current code, I just pasted an old version on accident. .submit() isn't working either though.

Comment: Can you give an example of your DOM layout? Also, where exactly in your page are you adding that event handler?

Comment: As @Derek has stated have you made sure `addhash` is the id of the form and not the submit button? Can you provide your HTML, an example website or jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @WillemEllis: FYI, submit button has nothing to do with form submission. You can submit a buttonless form.

Comment: I know. What are you saying that in reference to?

Comment: @WillemEllis: To "but the submit button is not being created dynamically" and Steven's "dynamically createing the submit button". Anyway, please verify that this code is more or less the same thing that you have: http://jsfiddle.net/fbA6M/1/ It works here in Firefox.

Comment: Also, you want to check that you have localStorage first. It can be disabled even in browsers that support it.

Comment: I verify that I have localStorage earlier in the script. @bvukelic, I will verify that code as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: I had a look at the code real quick, it looks almost exactly the same. What's different?

Comment: @WillemEllis: Nothing. That's the point. :)

Comment: Out of context, the above code should work even just by looking at it. There's nothing too exotic there. Maybe there is an issue somewhere else?

Comment: Haha, I don't know what's going on then. Could it have something to do with Twitter bootstrap?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22197/discussion-between-bvukelic-and-willem-ellis)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly your issue but

"As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers."

.live only needs to be used when the object/s selected don't exist in the DOM for all other cases you can use .bind() or in the case of your form .submit()